# The correct way to do parsing with StateT

Tags: haskell

Consider the following faulty parser written as `StateT`.

```
type Parser a = StateT String Maybe a -- Maybe is chosen arbitrarily here.

oneDigit :: Parser Int
oneDigit = do
        (x : _) <- get
        return (read x :: Int)
```

It throws following error:

```
No instance for (MonadState [String] (StateT String Maybe))
```

However, that didn't happen when I change to say, `oneChar :: Parser Char`.

My conclusion is that you can only define a `Parser a` if your State is `m a`

Now my question is, how do I loose this coupling requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your state is a `String`, if you do `(x : _) <- get` then `x` is a `Char`. You can't use `read` on a `Char`. The error printed is due to the type inference that works the other way around: from `read x` the compiler infers that `x` is a `String` and that means that your state is `[String]`, which is not true for `Parser a`. Specifically, the errors says that `(StateT String Maybe)` is not an instance of `MonadState [String]`, that is true because it is an instance of `MonadState String`. You can see it from GHCI:

```
> import Control.Monad.State
> :i StateT
...
instance Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m)
```

Where `s == String` in your case.

Now, if you want to read the next `Char` in your string as a digit (a num from 0 to 9), you need to replace `read` with `digitToInt` from `Data.Char`:

```
oneDigit :: Parser Int
oneDigit = do
    (x : _) <- get -- x will be inferred as Char
    return (digitToInt x :: Int)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type error is trying to tell you that your state needs to be a list of strings instead of a single string, because you use

```
(x : _) <- get
```

to get the first element of the list and then read it with `read` (which expects a `String`).

Since you only want to parse a single digit, you can change the function to

```
oneDigit :: Parser Int
oneDigit = do
        (x : _) <- get
        return (read [x] :: Int)
```

`[x]` creates a string from the single character (since `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`).

Note that you probably don't want to use `read` in a parser implementation because it will crash with invalid input. [`reads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads) is a slightly better alternative that lets you handle error cases. For example:

```
oneDigit :: Parser Int
oneDigit = do
    (x : xs) <- get
    case reads [x] of
        [(n, "")] -> put xs >> return n
        _         -> lift Nothing
```

This also `put`s the rest of the string back to the state so that your parser actually consumes input when it succeeds.